# UIWebView with Custom Gestures

Tags: uiwebview, uigesturerecognizer

As of right now I have a View with a UIWebView inside of it and some added custom gestures. Some examples of these gesture are `Two Finger Slide Right to Go Back`, `Two Finger Slide Left to Go Forward`, `Two Finger Long Press for Refresh`, ect.. But now I'm facing an issue I knew I would have to face when I began developing this app:

All of the gestures work great **unless** the UIWebView is zoomed in. Even if it is zoomed in the tiniest bit (or you are able to scroll the web page horizontally), the gestures that require you to swipe left or right are suddenly disabled because UIWebView takes first priority over these gestures.

[image: http://i47.tinypic.com/243rdyx.png]

If anyone can shine some light on this issue or even provide a work-around, I would be very grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm more familiar with OS X, but could you subclass UIWebView to remove this behavior?